# How make iOS app running on background forever in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to make an app that makes HTTP request to a website periodically. The app has to run in the background, but can wake up or show a notification, depending on a response of request. Like a message of WhatsApp, but I don't have a webserver, only the device check values of the http get request.

Comment: You need to look into the background fetch capability of iOS apps.

Comment: Apple restricts the use of background operations forever, only you can perform it for a finite amount of time because of extending the battery life.

Comment: See this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: @VinothVino The background fetch capability describes almost this exact use case, and is documented in the link you provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done with the `fetch` capability mentioned in the [iOS Background Execution guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). You need to include the 'Background fetch' option in your app's capabilities, and then implement the `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)` method in your application delegate. Then, this method will be called when iOS think's it is a good time to download some content. You can use `URLSession` and the associated methods to download whatever you want, and then call the provided completion handler, indicating whether content was available.

Note that this does not allow you to *schedule* such downloads, or have any control over when (or even if) they happen. The operating system will call the above method only when it decides that it is a good time. Apple's docs explain:

> Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches. The system must balance your app’s need to fetch content with the needs of other apps and the system itself. After assessing that information, the system gives time to apps when there are good opportunities to do so.

As an example, here is a basic implementation which initiates a download and then schedules a local notification for ten seconds from now if we get a good response:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://example.com/backgroundfetch")!) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        guard let info = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            completionHandler(.failed)
            return
        }
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Update!"
        content.body = info

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "UpdateNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

The [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html) should be used as the reference for implementing notifications.

Comment: The Apple Push Notification Service is not free, because of that I want implements a backgroud request. But, unfortunately, your solution can't scheduled. I go try implement this and analysing the result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue? This only uses local notifications, which are free.

Comment: I'am using the Firebase Cloud Function to make a HTTP Request periodically, using a cron job. The result of the request I want send to my device (iOS) through PubSub, but for this, I need a Apple Notification Push Service. If I write the solution of this answer, I can't configure a scheduled function, because I want make this periodically.